# How can I get specific data element in a text file

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I have a text file and two columns in it(name and birthday). And in first column I have two names(john and brayn). I only want to get name **brayn** and his birthday. How can I do this?

my text file:

**name**  **birthday**
john    1991
brayn    1994

Below the code snippet that I tried:

```
import java.io.*;

class Detail{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        users u=new users();
        if(args.length==1){
            System.out.println("No Details");
        }else{
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("users.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer= new BufferedReader(reader);

            String line = null;

            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                u.addToSearchString(line+'\n');
            }
            buffer.close();
            u.printName();
            }
        }
} 

class users{

    String names;

    users(){
        names=new String();
    }

    void addToSearchString(String add){
        names += add;
    }

    void printName() {
        int i = 0;
        int find, start, end;
        while ((find = names.indexOf("name:", i))!=-1){
            start = find + 5;
            end = names.indexOf("\t", start);
            System.out.println(names.substring(start, end));
            i = end + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Only want to get **brayn**'s row in the text file and assign it to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each line will always have the format in your sample data above, then you can simply split each line of the text file and retain the second string:

```
String line = "name: brayn birthday: 1994";
String[] parts = line.split(" ");

String name = parts[1];
System.out.println(name);
```

**Output:**

```
brayn
```

Comment: It's right can't I use printName() method to parameter to check the name.

Comment: Your method for finding the name might be more robust than splitting the line, the latter which assumes each line has the same structure.  Do you expect that each line might have a different structure?